# How do I build my Svelte website with all relative paths?

Tags: javascript, html, bundle, svelte

My website contains different 'projects' that are each linked to their own Git repositories and built from Netlify. For example if my website is `www.thedivtagguy.com`, `www.thedivtagguy.com/project1` and `www.thedivtagguy.com/project2` are two different websites but linked to the main domain as sub-directories (instead of `project1.thedivtagguy.com`).

One such example site is available [here](https://thedivtagguy2.netlify.app). As you can see, it renders all the styles correctly. However, if I access it through a redirect from my main site, [this is what happens](https://thedivtagguy.com/testing). There are no styles.

For the above, I am just setting a redirect rule to link `/testing/` to `https://thedivtagguy2.netlify.app`.

This is what the `public` directory looks like when I run npm build:

```
public
 ┣ api
 ┣ assets
 ┣ common
 ┣ app.css
 ┗ index.html
```

Even when run locally, index.html does not render the correct styles. This is what is contained in the `<head>` tag of index.html:

```html
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/start-428f887f.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/chunks/vendor-28205438.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/pages/__layout.svelte-da7e95f6.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/pages/index.svelte-33b339ff.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/chunks/Meta-7977247e.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_app/assets/start-c446e5f0.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_app/assets/pages/__layout.svelte-aa99de20.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_app/assets/pages/index.svelte-e673c7ca.css">

        <script type="module">
            import { start } from "/_app/start-428f887f.js";
            start({
                target: document.querySelector("#svelte"),
                paths: {"base":"","assets":""},
                session: {},
                host: location.host,
                route: true,
                spa: false,
                trailing_slash: "never",
                hydrate: {
                    status: 200,
                    error: null,
                    nodes: [
                        import("/_app/pages/__layout.svelte-da7e95f6.js"),
                        import("/_app/pages/index.svelte-33b339ff.js")
                    ],
                    page: {
                        host: location.host, // TODO this is redundant
                        path: "\u002F",
                        query: new URLSearchParams(""),
                        params: {}
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```

As you can see, it seems to be referencing some different paths altogether for styles, images and the JS bundles.

My intuitive guess is that I need to set the correct relative paths for my builds, so that it will work when built locally and when accessed via a redirect.

How do I do that? How can this be fixed so that my styles and other assets are rendered correctly?

My repository for this is [here](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/website2).

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

In `vite.config.ts` (presumably `vite.config.js` if you're not using TypeScript), add `base: './'` to the configuration.

Comment: I have never seen so much code inside svelte.config.js.

Comment: I found it. In package.json for build scripts you have "vite build --base=./". :-)