# Set relative path folder in Svelte Build

Tags: build, compilation, config, svelte, relative-path

## Set relative path folder in Svelte build

When I build my svelte app with the command `npm run build`, it's export the links like this:

```js
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-54c7d896.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-d3d038e5.css">
```

More accurately it call to the root `localhost/assets...`

```js
    // src="/assets/index-54c7d896.js"
    // href="/assets/index-d3d038e5.css"
```

And I get this:

[Error from the navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQKw.png)

From here:

[where I want use the svelte app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFIfk.png)

**And easy solution is using a relative path to:**

```js
// from "/assets/..." to "./assets/..."
src="./assets/index-54c7d896.js"
href="./assets/index-d3d038e5.css"
```

But the thing is I can't do that inside **javascript and css files**.
These still use an absolute path.

So this is what happens:

[when a css file call other files using absolute path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AD6c.png)

> I mean I could dig into a compiled file but it's not efficient

I tried **change manually** the paths on each file but it's a **lot of work** each time than I have **to compile.**

I'm using a hosting with php so I tried using **.htaccess** but it's hard too.

#### I am expecting this to be configurable from svelte.

##### I really love ❤️ this framework, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can set `server.base` option, as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481804